# Linux, supporting slightly different board variations, same SOC

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I'm currently using an i.MX6 from freescale with a linux build. We have slightly different boards and I'm tying to find a good example or maybe idea on how to support a few different variations of a board easily in the linux kernel.

The one thing I'm trying to do is avoid piles of if statements as much as I can. Its bad enough (after outsourcing) that our entire board init is basically in a single file. Its WONDERFUL to look at. But after looking around a bit more it appears this is fairly normal...

My first idea was to borrow from our previous WinCE build where we used a struct to hold all the information about a platform (gpio mappings, special/different hardware) so when the board init ran it would read a platform ID, then init all the information dynamically. This turned out to be... difficult as everything is pre baked in as static some_device_data data[]. Since it s all pre baked its hard to access in another init. It also felt... a little odd exporting everything out of a file.

My second idea was to just copy the board init, into two separate inits. From the main board init I could call whichever i needed but... It seems like there is a lot of duplication and it becomes difficult to maintain.

I guess the first important thing to ask is... does linux provide a smart way to manage small variations of boards. I know our product will go through many small iterations and being able to take one kernel for all is important.

If there isn't a smart way to do it, then what is the least painful? If statements seem to be the most painful as our last product went through about 20 different variations over its lifetime(these are supported for a long time, and end of life pieces happen often)

Comment: I think that's what [Device Tree](http://www.devicetree.org/Main_Page) is made for

Comment: @Kevin Take a look at how this is done with different ARM boards.  board-dream and board-halibut use the same chip set, but are laid out differently.  FWIW, these are Android apps processor boards.  http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-msm/?v=2.6.33;a=arm

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at [device tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_tree) :

The device tree is a data structure for describing hardware.
Given the correct device tree, the same compiled kernel can support different hardware configurations within a wider architecture family. The Linux kernel can read device tree information in the ARM, x86, MicroBlaze, PowerPC, and SPARC architectures. For ARM, use of device trees has become mandatory for all new SoCs.

Some links :

[Arm support in linux kernel](https://archive.fosdem.org/2013/schedule/event/arm_in_the_linux_kernel/attachments/slides/273/export/events/attachments/arm_in_the_linux_kernel/slides/273/arm_support_kernel.pdf)

[eLinux](http://elinux.org/Device_Tree)

[Arm SoC Check-List](http://www.elinux.org/images/a/ad/Arm-soc-checklist.pdf)

[Device Tree for Dummies](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/petazzoni-device-tree-dummies.pdf)

Comment: Am I able to pass in platform_device data? For instance my keypad is using the same controller device on both of our current systems. But one has a different number of keys and they are mapped in a little different.

So what I have to do is an if(plat) register_platform_defice(&keys_plata) else ...

Comment: I found http://lwn.net/Articles/448502/ this. Its a few years old but it seems like we'd have to modify all of the drivers to use the device tree?